# QT build error: "WARNING: TARGET is empty" and "make: nothing to be done for "first""

Tags: qt

I recently installed qt5 on Raspbian. I'm trying to compile [this package](https://github.com/groupgets/LeptonModule/tree/master/software/raspberrypi_qt) so I ran`qmake && make`. I get these errors:

```
WARNING: TARGET is empty
make: nothing to be done for 'first'
```

Before having qt5 (and qt-creator), I can compile the code seamlessly with qt4 installed in my raspberry pi. So I think it could be some incompatibility issue with qt5. How can I build this code without having to revert back to qt4?

*Note: I'm new with Qt and Raspberry pi.*

Comment: You are trying to compile the software written for Qt4 with Qt5 installed.

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion, is maybe try to see if you inadvertently used the wrong qmake. There is one in /usr/bin.

If there are multiple Qt versions installed it can get messed up if you accidentally run the wrong qmake, so maybe check your path points to the intended Qt version of make. If it has run qmake already with the wrong version, then I have found to cleanup you should run "make distclean" that cleans up the make files, then run qmake again, being sure it has the right path, which will generate the Makefile again. Qt seems to be smart enough to set all the right paths up *so long* as you run (the right) qmake first.